# "Your letter was received last Friday" or "Your letter is received last Friday"?

Tags: grammaticality, tense, passive-voice

Are the following sentences correct? If not, what's the correct usage?

> Your letter **was received** last Friday.
>
> Your letter **is received** last Friday.

Comment: You cannot use present tense with "last Friday". The correct version is: "Your letter **was** received last Friday".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Your mail is received." or "Your mail was received."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4646/your-mail-is-received-or-your-mail-was-received)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Your letter was received last Friday" is the correct sentence. "Last Friday" uses *past tense* (is referencing a previous event), and "was" is past tense; therefore, the two excerpts match.

If you were referencing an *ongoing event*, such as "your letter is received every Friday," then "is" would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use present tense with “last Friday.” The correct version is:

> Your letter **was** received last Friday.

([Source](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11465/referring-to-a-past-event#comment-19468))